# "For your protection, access to this resource is secured against CSRF" error in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, correlation

I am trying to record and run a mailing system in which i am supposed to perform correlation so that jmeter tool could log in to the mail box but in this application many dynamic values are coming in the response header as Set-Cookie and another one is Set-Cookie :{dynamic value}- followed by some number. I have added the RegEx which will fetch the dynamic value, put in to some variable and pass on to the further request. But this is not working, I have put a debug sampler where it says roundCube_id_not_found which means dynamic value is not extracted itself. Plz help
attaching the screenshots here for your reference
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMvbH.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRYVu.png)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you without seeing:

1. At least partial response with the value you're trying to correlate
2. Your [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) configuration

In the meantime be informed that:

1. You don't need to manually handle cookies, JMeter's [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager) can do this for you. If you need to save a cookie value into a JMeter Variable set `CookieManager.save.cookies` property to `true`
2. JMeter provides [Mail Reader Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler), if you need to read an email it will be way faster and easier to use rather than trying to get the email from the roundcude web interface.

Comment: hi Dmitri, I have added screenshots for your reference. please have a look and I have already added a cookie manager but how to set the cookie manager property as true? and I am avoiding to use mail reader sampler since I want to practice more on correlation, like the conventional way.

Comment: If you want to use Regular Expression Extractor - change "Field to check" to `Response headers` instead of `Body` as [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) is a **response header**. If you want to use the Cookie Manager add `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) and restart JMeter to pick up the change. More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)